# How to check how many React children have a certain prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two types of components. Let's call them Outer and Inner. Imagine something like this:

```
<Outer>
    <h4>{this.prop.title} ({this.state.withX}/{this.state.total})</h4>
    <Inner isX/>
    <Inner isX/>
    <Inner/>
    <Inner/>
</Outer>
```

I have this function:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        total: React.Children.count(this.props.children),
        withX: /// ??? ///
    };
}
```

How do I get that value? I was trying to get something like this:

```
withX: function() {
    var counter = React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function(child) {
         // if...
         return //something
    });
return counter;
}
```

But... I feel it'll get me nowhere.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you iterate over the children, you can inspect their props. For instance, using the `forEach` method you have above, you could do something like this:

```
withX: function() {
  var counter = 0;
  React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function(child) {
    if (child.props.isX) counter++;
  });
  return counter;
}
```

React also provides a [`toArray` helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.toarray) that lets you do the same thing using the nice array methods JS provides:

```
return React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).filter(function(child) {
  return child.props.isX;
}).length;
```

If you're using ES6, can do this quite succinctly with an arrow function:

```
return React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).filter(c => c.props.isX).length;
```

The only catch is that, if `Outer` is doing the counting, then `Outer` also needs to render the `h4`. Here's a full example:

```
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Outer title="Things">
        <Inner isX/>
        <Inner isX/>
        <Inner/>
        <Inner/>
      </Outer>
    );
  }
});

const Outer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      total: React.Children.count(this.props.children),
      withX: this.countChildrenWithX(this.props.children)
    };
  },

  countChildrenWithX(children) {
    const { toArray } = React.Children;
    return toArray(children).filter(c => c.props.isX).length;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.props.title} ({this.state.withX}/{this.state.total})</h4>
        <hr />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const Inner = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>Inner - withX = {String(!!this.props.isX)}</div>;
  }
});
```

And [here's a working JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xameyun/edit?js,output) to demonstrate: https://jsbin.com/xameyun/edit?js,output

Comment: Hah! That's a great answer. Thank you, very informative. I'm happy to see I was thinking in a proper direction. I'm very happy that you have shown various ways to achieve the same thing. The ES6 syntax is just perfect.

Answer (score 54):

React now has `React.Children.count(children)` method documented here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.count

UPDATE:
upon reflection, I'm not sure this actually answers the question, but will leave here anyway as people have already voted on it.

Comment: This helped me in my situation. I was testing to see how many children I have in my parent component, but could not use the map() function, since it does not work if there is only one child.  In my case this was a great solve to count children. Thanks a lot